# Convert literal backslash followed by a character to the corresponding escape sequence

Tags: javascript, escaping

I have an incoming string that contains a literal backslash followed by n, `"\\n"`. How can I interpret this is a newline, `"\n"`? Similarly for `"\\t"` → `"\t"`. I want to interpret a literal backslash followed by a character as the corresponding escape sequence.

Input: `"foo\\nbar\\tbaz"`. Desired output: `"foo\nbar\tbaz"`.

Comment: does this work .replace("\\n", "\n")?

Comment: Is there a way to do this without specifying every possible escape sequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to write out every single replacement, one ugly possibility would be to use `eval` to interpret the `\` followed by the escaped character as a string:

```js
const input = String.raw`foo\nbar\tbaz`;
console.log(input.replace(/\\(.)/g, (_, char) => eval('"\\' + char + '"')));
```

Comment: It's ugly but it works... if a better answer doesn't come along, I'll accept this

Answer (score 0):

Another option - leverage JSON module:

```
const s = 'foo\\nbar\\tbaz';
console.log(JSON.parse('["' + s + '"]')[0]);
```

Comment: This fails if `s` has a double quote in it